# Can't share to linkedin using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, ios9, xcode7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I can't share anything via linkedin using `UIActivityViewController`. While I tap share via linkedin, it opens the sharing pop up and dismisses immediately after opened it. All other sharing are working fine. Could you please tell me a solution? Thanks.

> Note: my project is in ios9 and xcode version is 7

and my error log shows : `plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension interrupted`

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Ideally I would be able to share a UIImage, NSUrl, and NSString. I've tried returning nil for each or all of these for the case of LinkedIn to no avail.

Comment: @Mumthezir have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Mumthezir hey, I dont even see linkedin on my UIActivityViewController, did you implement a custom activityType?

Answer (score 4):

The iOS 8 extensions cannot be presented in a custom share screen. You absolutely have to use UIActivityViewController in order for the share/action extensions to appear.

Comment: we are using the same UIActivityViewController.

Comment: One change is to use image object instead of NSData object in UIAcitvityViewController but that's also not working with LinkedIn.!

Answer (score 0):

Have you written the code like this

```
DataItemProvider *dataToShare = [[DataItemProvider alloc] initWithPlaceholderItem:FileTypeToShare];

LinkedInActivityType *linkedinActivity = [[LinkedInActivityType alloc] init];

NSArray *activityTypes = @[linkedinActivity];
NSArray *activityItems = @[dataToShare];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:activityTypes];

[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    //Put in your completion handle code here.
}];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```